# Error when install xampp

Tags: xampp

when using apt-get install xampp
i get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xampp
```

How can i fix this, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xampp is not in ubuntu repository. You must download the installer from the xampp website, and follow their instructions.

To resume with command lines:

```
$ wget https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/5.6.15/xampp-linux-x64-5.6.15-1-installer.run
$ chmod 755 xampp-linux-*-installer.run
$ sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
```

See https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html

Answer (score 1):

xampp is not in the default Ubuntu repository, you can check this :

```
sudo apt-cache search xampp
```

you need to either install it manually or add a PPA

**Update:**
 (apparently there is no working PPA for xampp anymore)
You have the full instructions, step by step in this blog post:
[Install Latest Xampp 7.0.2 on Linux Ubuntu Derivative System](http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2016/02/install-latest-xampp-702-on-linjux.html):

for **32bit**:

```
 wget https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.0.2/xampp-linux-7.0.2-1-installer.run && sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-7.0.2-1-installer.run && sudo ./xampp-linux-7.0.2-1-installer.run
```

for **64bit**:

```
wget https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.0.2/xampp-linux-x64-7.0.2-1-installer.run && sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.0.2-1-installer.run && sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.0.2-1-installer.run
```